# Can I get correct version and build info when doing "go get path/to/myapp"?

Tags: go

I need to provide a version number in the output generated by Go app.
For releases and local builds I use Makefile that has:

```
...
VERSION = $(shell git describe --tags)
VER = $(shell git describe --tags --abbrev=0)
DATE = $(shell date -u '+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S%Z')
...
FLAGS_LD=-ldflags "-X path/to/myapp/mypkg.Build=${DATE} \
                  -X path/to/myapp/mypkg.Version=${VERSION}"
...
GOCMD = go
GOBUILD = $(GOCMD) build $(FLAGS_LD)
GOINSTALL = $(GOCMD) install $(FLAGS_LD)
...
```

And in the package I have variables as

```
package mypkg

var (
    Version = "v0.11.0-dev"
    Build   string
)
```

All is well when I run build, install or release via make, but if I run
`go get path/to/myapp` then `-ldflags` are empty and user gets outdated version information, and
no build information.

Is there a way to get correct ldflags data when installing a program with `go get`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No, you cannot read/write ldflags when downloading sources

`go get` is meant to install from sources.

> Is there a way to get correct ldflags data when installing a program with go get?

The current response is no.

#### Yes, you can provide your users with your package's version

The simplest way to achieve what you're wanting to do is either :

1. If what you want to share is a *lib* (re-useable code), add git tags to your source repo so that your dev-users can use it for package version management. (glide, go.mod, dep, ...).
2. If what you want to share is a *program* (meant to be compiled and executed only), modify the value of `Version` each time you make a new release. You can perform this automatically very easily with a combination of `git-hooks` and `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get correct ldflags data when installing a program with go get?

No.